# Search for substring in folder names

Tags: batch-file, search, substring, directory

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

There is a directory containing folders for every order, e.g.

```
L:\Med_Department\Orders\
L:\Med_Department\Orders\T0012345_AB100_CustomerA_site2
L:\Med_Department\Orders\T0012346_CD350-CustomerB site1
...
```

How can I get the full name of a folder by searching for the order number. 
When I enter the order number for example:

> T0012345

, 
I want the script to store

> T0012345_AB100_CustomerA_site2

in a variable so I can use it to create the folder for my new project instead of the order number.

The order number is unique and has the format Txxxxxxx . The rest of the folder name can be separated by underscore, blank space or other characters.

If the order number is not found (e.g. order number not entered correctly) the user should enter the order number again.

This is what I achieved so far.
I enter the order number and the script copies a template folder into my projects directory with the order number as folder name.

```
@Echo off

rem directories
set template= "N:\Documentation\New_folder_OrderNo-Type-Customer-site"
set dirOrder= "L:\Med_Department\Orders\"
SET dirProjects= "Z:\Projects\2016\"

rem input Order No.
echo Please enter the order number?
echo.
set /p OrderNo=OrderNo:

rem target directory 
set dirNewProject=%dirProjects%%OrderNo%\
echo %dirnewProject%

pause
rem copy content from template into target directory
xcopy %template% %dirNewProject% /S /E /C /H /O /R /Y /D /V

rem open target directory
explorer %dirNewProject%

;exit
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `;exit` does not comment out the `exit` command as `;` is nothing but a token separator (like also the _space_), so `exit` is going to be executed; to comment it out, use `rem exit` or `:: exit`; by the way, `exit` terminates the `cmd` instance the batch file is running in, while `exit /B` quits the batch file only; see also `exit /?`...

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
@Echo off

rem directories
set template= "N:\Documentation\New_folder_OrderNo-Type-Customer-site"
set dirOrder = "L:\Med_Department\Orders\"
SET dirProjects= "Z:\Projects\2016\"

:again
rem input Order No.
echo Please enter the order number?
echo.
set /p OrderNo=OrderNo:



if not exist "%dirOrder%%OrderNo%\" (
    echo order %OrderNo%  not found
    goto :again
)

:: the rest of the script
:: ...
```

?

Comment: Sorry I was to slow to edit my comment. The real problem for me is how do I get the whole foldername when I just enter the order number and not the whole folder name. In your solution I have to enter T0012345_AB100_CustomerA_site2 to check if the folder exists. But I just want to enter T0012345 and the script should check if a folder starting T0012345_AB100_CustomerA_site2 exists and return the whole folder name as a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

use a `for` to get the output of a command. Use `dir` with proper switches to do a wildcard search (Note: with `dir` wildcards do only work within the very last element of a path).

```
:again
set /p "OrderNo=OrderNo: "
set "folder=none"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /ad /b %dirOrder%%OrderNo%*') do set folder=%%a
if %folder% == none goto :again
echo found: %folder%
```

see `for /?` and `dir /?` for details

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `for /D` against the pattern `%OrderNo%*`. If there is folder whose name starts with `%OrderNo%` (there should be one only, if I got it right), `dirNewProject` is going to hold its path; if there is none, the variable is going to be empty. You can chek `if [not] defined dirNewProject` afterwards and jump to a `:LABEL` contitionally:

```
rem (skipping data entry part of script)

rem directory 
set "dirNewProject="
for /D %%I in ("%dirProjects%\%OrderNo%*") do set "dirNewProject=%%I"
if not defined dirNewProject goto :LABEL

rem (skipping file copy part of script)
```

Comment: @Compo So sorry by edit the answer today, this is for to perform a tried, to improve your affirmations on, please, consider my limited English, so, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Example...**(Untested)

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal

Rem directories
(Set template=N:\Documentation\New_folder_OrderNo-Type-Customer-site)
(Set dirOrder=L:\Med_Department\Orders)
(Set dirProjects=Z:\Projects\2016)

Rem exit if above directories do not exist
For %%a In (template dirOrder dirProjects) Do (If Not Exist "%%%%a%%\" Exit/B)

Rem make search dir current
If /I Not "%CD%" Equ "%dirOrder%" PushD %dirOrder%

:AskNum
Rem input Order No.
Echo(
Echo( Please enter the order number?
Echo(
Set/P "OrderNo=OrderNo: "

For /D %%a In ("%OrderNo%*") Do (Set OrderDir=%%~a)
If Not Defined OrderDir (Choice /C /M "Would you like to try again?"
    If Errorlevel 2 Exit/B
    GoTo :AskNum)

Rem new project directory 
(Set dirNewProject=%dirProjects%\%OrderDir%)

Rem copy content from template to new project directory
If Not Exist "%dirNewProject%\" (
    RoboCopy "%template%" "%dirNewProject%" /E /Copy:DATSO)

Rem open new project directory
Explorer "%dirNewProject%"
```